# Closed form for $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\Lambda(\frac{x}{k})}{k^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a closed form for the following?$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{\Lambda(\frac x k)}{k^2}$$

$\Lambda(x)$ is unit triangle defined as

$$
\Lambda(x) = \begin{cases}
            1+x, & -1 \leq x \lt 0 \\
            1-x, & 0 \leq x \leq 1
        \end{cases}
$$

All I can figure out is that the value at origin is $\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$, since it is a sum of reciprocals of squares. Any help?

Comment: $\Lambda(x)\zeta(3)$ , for $x\ne 0$ and $\zeta(2)$ for $x=0$. Maybe...

Answer (score 0):

Let's call $G(x)$ the sum of the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\Lambda(\frac{x}{k})}{k^2}$ where
$$\Lambda(x) = \begin{cases}
            1+x, & -1 \leq x \lt 0 \\
            1-x, & 0 \leq x \leq 1
        \end{cases}$$
Then we have 
$$G(x) = \begin{cases}
            0              & x=\pm 1\\
            (1+x)\zeta(3), & -1 < x < 0 \\
            \zeta(2)      & x=0\\
            (1-x)\zeta(3), & 0 < x < 1
        \end{cases}$$

Comment: But this sum (i.e. your $G(x)$ ), extends all the way to $\infty$ on x-axis. Your definition only covers the range [1,1]

Comment: @Srini Yes, exactly were the original $\Lambda$ was defined. Outside that interval we know nothing